# How to include/copy static files inside final docker image using fabric8 tools

Tags: openshift, fabric8

I'm using the Fabric8 Maven tool chain to build and deploy my Camel app on top of Openshift. I'm using the Camel Boot approach... My Mvn profile perform the following goals: `clean install docker:build fabric8:json fabric8:appl`.

Everything is ok! Except that I'm serving a static file (`index.html`) using `Jetty` as part of Camel route app. That file is located in `$MY_PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources`. So, it goes to the app's classpath after a normal `mvn build`. But when using `fabric8` build workflow, My app (Camel route) can't find that static content on filesystem classpath?

How can I specify fabric8 plugins to copy my static content inside `/deployments` of th final build image? Thus my camel endpoints ca refer to it on filesystem. I'm looking for something like `maven-resources-plugin`.

Comment: See documentation at https://maven.fabric8.io/

Answer (score 4):

Well, digging into the src code I discovery you have two option to achieve this...

1. **hawt-app-maven-plugin**

   if you are using `hawt-app-maven-plugin` [1], like me, you can use the `hawt-app.source` config property
   during the package/build process all the contents of directory (which defaults to `src/main/hawt-app`) specified in `hawt-app.source` will be copied to the `${project.build.directory}/hawt-app/`.
2. **docker-maven-plugin**

using the fabric8's `docker-maven-plugin` assembly configuration [2], you can pass a custom maven assembly descriptor. Like this one:

project's **pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId> 
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${docker.maven.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <images>
      <image>
        <name>${docker.image}</name>
        <build>
        <from>${docker.from}</from>
        <assembly>
          <basedir>/deployments</basedir>
          <!-- descriptorRef>hawt-app</descriptorRef -->
          <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hawt-app-custom-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </assembly>
```

**hawt-app-custom-assembly.xml**

```
<assembly ...>
  <id>hawt-app</id>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <includes>
        <include>bin/*</include>
      </includes>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/hawt-app</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <includes>
        <include>lib/*</include>
      </includes>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/hawt-app</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
    <!-- assembly extention... -->
    <fileSet>
      <includes>
        <include>static-content/*</include>
      </includes>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

[1] https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/tree/master/hawt-app-maven-plugin

[2] https://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:build

[3] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html